# Oracle column default value in .NET

Tags: .net, oracle

When I run the following SQL in Oracle, the column default value is reported correctly ('Test').  When I run the same SQL in .NET, the reported default value is NULL:

```
SELECT column_name, data_default FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name='MYTABLENAME'
```

The column in question is Varchar2. I also tested a number column - same problem.

The database version is Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

The .NET connector is ODP.NET

The operating system is Windows 7 / 64

I get the same result (NULL) from all_tab_columns

.NET Code:

```
Dim provider As DbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client")
Using connection As DbConnection = provider.CreateConnection
  connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost; User Id=userid; Password=password"
  connection.Open
  Using dt As New DataTable
    Using command As DbCommand = provider.CreateCommand
      command.CommandText = "SELECT column_name, data_default FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name='MYTABLENAME'"
      command.Connection = connection
      Using da As DbDataAdapter = provider.CreateDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = command
        da.Fill(dt)
      End Using
    End Using
    For Each row As DataRow in dt.Rows
      Response.Write(row("COLUMN_NAME") & " " & row("DATA_DEFAULT") & "<br>")
    Next
  End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Are you logging-in as the same user in both cases?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic yes

Comment: Can you post your .NET code? The Oracle query is fine so the problem must be there.

Comment: @EdGibbs .NET code added

Comment: Hmm, this appears to be solid. The only strange thing I see is this line: `Using command`. I work mostly with C# so my VB.NET is terrible, but in C# you're supposed to instantiate the variable in the `using` construct - you shouldn't instantiate it ahead of time and supply the instance variable to `Using` as you've done. A couple of things to try for diagnostic purposes: (1) see what happens if you change the `WHERE` clause of the query from `WHERE table_name='MYTABLENAME'` to `WHERE ROWNUM < 10`. (2) what happens if you get rid of the `Using command` wrapper?

Comment: @EdGibbs I tried `command.CommandText = "SELECT table_name, column_name, data_default FROM user_tab_columns"` to same result. Also tried refactoring the `DbCommand` (as per my updated code). No joy.

Comment: data_default is of type LONG, I wonder if this is somehow not supported in the .NET driver?

Comment: @ic3b3rg - I was about to say I had nothing else to suggest, but I just took a closer look at `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and `DATA_DEFAULT_VALUE` is type `LONG`. I'll take a look around and see if that's the problem.

Comment: Oops - Colin beat me to it :) I'm sure his answer (below) is the right one. The `LONG` datatype is a toughie because there's nothing you can do in the query to change it to a character; you'll need to handle it on the VB end. His link is a start but contains no examples. I Googled and found one decent one [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/lob.html). There's a VB example about halfway down the page; look for the `DownloadBlob` method.

Comment: @EdGibbs I also read that setting `command.InitialLongFetchSize = 1000` (it's 0 by default) may be a solution. However, I can't set that on `DbCommand` (errors out), it needs to be set on an `OracleCommand`. I can't use `OracleCommand` in my application, I need to use the `ProviderFactory.CreateCommand`. I'll look through the `DownloadBlob` example you provided.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a .NET programmer, just an Oracle expert. LONGs cause no end of grief and it's a shame that Oracle continues to use them in the data dictionary instead of a CLOB. There is a to_lob() function, but it can only be used in an insert statement, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions185.htm One approach that I've used is to create a temporary table in Oracle (which is a permanent table, just the contents are temporary) and fill it from the catalog. Then query the temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up creating an Oracle function to handle this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
  FUNCTION GetColumnDefaultValue(
    TableName IN varchar2,
    ColumnName IN varchar2
  )
  RETURN varchar2
    AS ddLong long; 
    BEGIN
      SELECT data_default
      INTO ddLong
      FROM user_tab_columns
      WHERE table_name = TableName
        AND column_name = ColumnName;
    RETURN
      substr(ddLong,0,255);
    END;
```

The default value is retrieved using:

```
SELECT GetColumnDefaultValue('TABLENAME','FIELDNAME') FROM dual
```

Note that this retrieves only the first byte of the default value.  Modify `substr(ddLong,0,255);` to return more.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I'm no Oracle expert, but what I've read on the web is that String functions can be used on Long fields within PLSQL. I've tested this function and it does work. I also found a low-level method in .NET to determine which data_default fields of user_tab_columns are not null, so I only need to use this function on those fields.

Answer (score 3):

data_default is of Oracle type LONG. Going by this documentation http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featData.htm#i1007197 it seems that you need to do some special work to retrieve LONG values.